# IF/ELSE Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can anyone please point out what im doing wrong with this Stored Procedure please. I cant get it to compile and my software isnt giving any useful clues as to what is wrong with it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE web.createSubscriptions
   (
   @Member_Id BIGINT,
   @Trans_type VARCHAR(100),
   @Payment_Status VARCHAR(100),
   @Payment_Date DATETIME,
   @Trans_Id VARCHAR(100)
   )

AS
DECLARE @tmpType VARCHAR(15)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TBL_SUBSCRIPTIONS (subs_MemberID, subs_Type, subs_Status, subs_DateGenerated, subs_PaypalTransaction) VALUES(@Member_Id, @Trans_Type, @Payment_Status, @Payment_Date, @Trans_Id)

IF(@Trans_type = 'subscr_signup')
    BEGIN
    @tmpType = 'premium'
    END
ELSE(@Trans_type = 'subscr_cancel')
    BEGIN
    @tmpType = 'basic'
    END

UPDATE TBL_MEMBERS
SET members_Type = @tmpType
WHERE members_Id = @Member_Id

END
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nick is right. The next error is the else should be else if (you currently have a boolean expression in your else which makes no sense). Here is what it should be

```
ELSE IF(@Trans_type = 'subscr_cancel')
    BEGIN
    SET @tmpType = 'basic'
    END
```

You currently have the following (which is wrong):

```
ELSE(@Trans_type = 'subscr_cancel')
    BEGIN
    SET @tmpType = 'basic'
    END
```

Here's a tip for the future- double click on the error and SQL Server management Studio will go to the line where the error resides. If you think SQL Server gives cryptic errors (which I don't think it does), then you haven't worked with Oracle!

Comment: @Munklefish hey but I'm glad you made it(not that I'm evil but..) cause this helped me with one basic question I thought about SQL :P

Answer (score 8):

It isn't giving any errors?
Try
`SET @tmpType = 'premium`'
and
`SET @tmpType = 'basic'`

Comment: I just tried that and it returns the following unhelpful error

Incorrect syntax near '@Trans_type'.

Comment: That's definitely part of the problem

Comment: My answer has the next fix. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Are you missing the 'SET' statement when assigning to your variables in the IF .. ELSE block?

Comment: I just tried that and it returns the following unhelpful error

"Incorrect syntax near '@Trans_type'"

Answer (score 1):

try

```
set @tmptype
```

Comment: I just tried that and it returns the following unhelpful error

"Incorrect syntax near '@Trans_type'"

Answer (score 1):

yeah Nick is right.

You need to use `SET` or `SELECT` to assign to @tmpType

Comment: I just tried that and it returns the following unhelpful error

"Incorrect syntax near '@Trans_type'"

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip for this, you don't need the BEGIN and END if it only contains a single statement.

ie:

```
IF(@Trans_type = 'subscr_signup')    
 set @tmpType = 'premium' 
ELSE iF(@Trans_type = 'subscr_cancel')  
     set    @tmpType = 'basic'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with SQL join statements

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteItem]
   @ItemId int = 0  
 AS
 Begin
 DECLARE @cnt int;

SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT @cnt =COUNT(ttm.Id) 
    from ItemTransaction itr INNER JOIN ItemUnitMeasurement ium 
        ON itr.Id = ium.ItemTransactionId  INNER JOIN ItemMaster im 
        ON itr.ItemId = im.Id INNER JOIN TransactionTypeMaster ttm 
        ON itr.TransactionTypeMasterId = ttm.Id 
        where im.Id = @ItemId

if(@cnt = 1)
    Begin
    DECLARE @transactionType varchar(255);
    DECLARE @mesurementAmount float;
    DECLARE @itemTransactionId int;
    DECLARE @itemUnitMeasurementId int;

        SELECT @transactionType = ttm.TransactionType,  @mesurementAmount = ium.Amount, @itemTransactionId = itr.Id, @itemUnitMeasurementId = ium.Id
        from ItemTransaction itr INNER JOIN ItemUnitMeasurement ium 
            ON itr.Id = ium.ItemTransactionId INNER JOIN TransactionTypeMaster ttm 
            ON itr.TransactionTypeMasterId = ttm.Id 
            where itr.ItemId = @ItemId  
        if(@transactionType = 'Close' and @mesurementAmount = 0)
            Begin
                delete from ItemUnitMeasurement where Id = @itemUnitMeasurementId;

            End
        else
            Begin
                delete from ItemTransaction where Id = @itemTransactionId;
            End
    End
else
 Begin
    delete from ItemMaster where Id = @ItemId;
 End

END
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
IF(@Trans_type = 'subscr_signup')    
BEGIN 
 set @tmpType = 'premium' 
 END
ELSE iF(@Trans_type = 'subscr_cancel')  
  begin
     set    @tmpType = 'basic'  
  END
```

Comment: bit of an odd comment coming so long after the real answer has been revealed. ;-)